# Real world examples of continuous uniform distribution on [0,1]

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Can someone give me real world examples of uniform distribution on [0,1] of a continuous random variable, because I could not make out one.

Comment: Maybe raindrops falling on a ruler.

Answer (score 5):

Consider a "spinner": an object like an unmagnetized compass needle that can pivots freely around an axis, and is stable pointing in any direction.  You give it a spin and see where it comes to rest, measuring the resulting angle (divided by $2\pi$) as a number from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: I am bit confused, when i look into the PDF for this distribution, when its divides by 2π, the probability of each outcome turns out be 1. I mean when draw a PDF we get a horizontal straight line at 1. However the chance of getting a value within the range 0 to 360 (2π) = 1/ 360, so when I plot the PDF for 0 to 360, it is a straight line at 0.0028, where as when i divide the same by 360 its a straight line at 1. I know the area under the curve for PDF 1 but, just becoz I divided by 360, why is the chance of occurrence or probability for each out come increases to 1 rather than 0.0028?

Comment: The probability of each outcome (i.e. each real number in the interval $[0,1]$) is $0$.  The PDF value is a density, not a probability.  If you graph it, probability corresponds to area under the curve.  For a uniform distribution on $[0,360]$ the PDF would be $f(x) = 1/360$ for $0 \le x \le 360$: corresponding to the area  of a rectangle of width $360$ and height $1/360$ is $1$.

Answer (score 3):

You show up at a bus stop to wait for a bus that comes by once per hour. You do not know what time the bus came by last. The arrival time of the next bus is a continuous uniform distribution [0,1] measured in hours.

Answer (score 2):

In analog-to-digital conversion a quantization error occurs. This error is either due to rounding or truncation. When the original signal is much larger than one least significant bit (LSB), the quantization error is not significantly correlated with the signal, and has an approximately uniform distribution. The RMS error therefore follows from the variance of this distribution.

Answer (score 1):

This is like the spinner example. Consider throwing a dart at a dart board. Assuming that all directions are equally likely, the angle of deflection from the x-axis drawn through the bullseye should be uniformly distributed between $0$ and $360^\circ$ or $0$ and $2 \pi$. Rescaling would produce a uniform $0$, $1$.

Answer (score -1):

Well to simulate a normal distribution in Excel one first simulates a uniform random variable $U \sim Unif(0,1)$ and then computes the value $x$ s.t.

$$U = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(t) dt$$

where $f_X(t)$ is the pdf of a normal distribution with mean and std dev $(\mu, \sigma^2)$

Essentially, the simulation of a number in $(0,1)$ here is the simulation of a probability.

Comment: Whenever I need to generate random variables with normal distribution I simply generate two random variables uniformly distributed on $[0,1)$. Then use them to get the polar coordinates of a point $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2$ with $x$ and $y$ i.i.d. $(\mu=0,\sigma=1)$ normals. The $r$-coordinate has Rayleigh distribution with a known elementary cdf, and the angle coordinate is uniformly distributed in $[0,2\pi)$. I did not downvote but I think my method is standard and more efficient than what you describe - no need for table look-ups of the inverse of the cdf of a normal.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, this is called the Box-Muller algorithm and it is much more efficient than CDF lookup for the case of the normal distribution. I think most "randn" implementations instead use the ziggurat algorithm.

Answer (score -4):

If there are N raffle tickets sold to N different people, then each ticket holder has the same probability of winning the prize. The distribution is uniform.

Comment: But the variable is not a continuous random variable